# Java Android get search term in a quest

Tags: java, android, string, search, text

I have any question like `What is java`. Out of this question I want to filter out the search term to do an auto search on Google, in this case the search term is: `java`.
Another example:
Question:

```
What is the opposite of long?
```

The search term is:

```
opposite of long
```

Comment: In a database (which is what you are supposed to use), you can use the SQL `LIKE` operator.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the layout of the question you can use Strings substring method.

```
String question = "What is the opposite of long?";
String searchTerm = question.substring(9, question.length() - 1);
```

Edit:
This works only for this type of question so if you want to apply a  custom semantic filter do it like this:

```
String question = "What is the opposite of long?";
String[] invalidSearchValues = {"Where", "What", "Why", "?", "!"};
String[] questionWords = question.split(" ");
String searchTerm = "";

for (String word : questionWords) {
    if (!Arrays.asList(invalidSearchValues).contains(word)) {
        searchTerm+= " " + word;
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant the search term of any question not especially this one

Comment: It works for every question starting with "What is " and ends with "?", you want to implement a semantic filter for the question which is quit difficult. As an alternative you can split the String by spaces and filter every questioning word and symbol out of it.

Comment: Thats Not my problem